# Tense in "Chaque jour + past"

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

> Quand j'étais enfant, chaque jour ma mère ___ un conte.

Should the passé composé *m'a lu* or the imparfait *me lisait* go there? I tend toward the imparfait because the sentence is about an action that took place regularly in the past, but the use of *chaque jour* makes me unsure, since the action only took place once each day.

Comment: (among other things) Imparfait details what used to happen on a regular basis, or happened an indefinite number of times. And _chaque jour_ is quite regular :)

Comment: PC is possible, but wouldn't be the most common way to fill the blank, I think. It would insist on the literal claim of having been read to each and every day. "My mom read to me every one of those days" (PC) instead of "My mom would read to me every day" (imparfait), or something. That's my sense, anyway.

Comment: Agree with Luke. Default would be the imperfect (habitual), but the PC is possible if insisting on/counting individual events (e.g. i it said "ce mois-là" instead of "quand j'étais enfant").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the imparfait:

> Quand j’étais enfant, chaque jour ma mère me lisait un conte.

Comment: That's right. Anyway, as the OP is learning, I think you could have added an explanation about *why* imparfait is the good choice.

Comment: The problem is that I just don't know why. I'm just a french bad at grammar. :D